# How can I properly position a nested <ul> above a horizontally scrollable <ul> as a "pop-up" menu? Issues with Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontally scrolling menu that also has pop-up sub-menu items and I'm wrestling with some issues.

I found a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477834/div-with-scroll-and-content-with-absolute-positions), but when I try to utilize the suggested answer of setting position: relative; on the parent of the absolutely positioned element (in this case the "pop-up" menu) then I run into overflow issues.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxjuev3b/5/) so you can see what I'm running into and maybe provide some feedback.  Firefox works fine as is, but IE and Chrome both have issues with the position of the pop-up menu for "Four" and later as you scroll right.

Note that mousing over the yellow boxes shows a pop-up menu directly above that element, but as you scroll right and start mousing over elements the pop-up menu no longer aligns properly.  I tried to set the position of the main `<ul>` to "relative" but that's when I run into issues with the pop-up not showing up (even after adjusting the "bottom" to something other than 100px).

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-outer">
    <div class="modal-inner">
      <div class="project_navigation">
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">One</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">One A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">One B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">One C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">One D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Two</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Two A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Two B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Two C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Two D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Three</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Three A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Three B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Three C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Three D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Four</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Four A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Four B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Four C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Four D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Five</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Five A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Five B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Five C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Five D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Six</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Six A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Six B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Six C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Six D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Seven</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Seven A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Seven B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Seven C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Seven D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Eight</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Eight A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Eight B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Eight C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Eight D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Nine</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Nine A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Nine B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Nine C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Nine D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Ten</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Ten A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Ten B</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Ten C</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Ten D</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    background: #4c3416;
    background: rgba(76, 52, 22, 0.65);
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1050;
}
.modal-container {
  margin-left: 0;
    left: auto;
    height: 125px;
    position: fixed;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #4c3416;
    border-radius: 0;
    right: auto;
    color: #4c3416;
    min-height: initial;
}
.modal-outer {
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: initial;
  background-color: blue;
}

.modal-inner {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.project_navigation {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: white
  list-style: none;
}

.project_navigation > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.project_navigation > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.project_navigation > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: auto;
  width: 125px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #00ff99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue a while back and [this link](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) helped me sort through it. The main point was to wrap your sub-menus in a wrapper class which will serve as their positioning ancestor instead (since right now it seems that your whole inline-block is doing this which is what you don't want).