# CSS position absolute over scrollbar

Tags: css

I have a content  with horizontal scroll. Inside there are some parent divs with a hidden child  with position absolute that only show on click.

My problem is that when I scroll content, children div show "where parent would be without scroll" (which is righter when scrolled right). To fix this I added position:relative to parent divs, and now it shows where it should, but children div got "truncated" by scroll bar (before adding position:relative to parent, child div showed over the scroll bar).

What am I missing to get both things working? (right position and over scrollbar)

Thanks

PS: related post: [Div with scroll and content with absolute positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477834/div-with-scroll-and-content-with-absolute-positions)

Edit: I couldn't make a "simple working" fiddle, here is one image with parent position relative and one with parent position not relative
[image: child div is out of place]
child is out of place

[image]
child is "truncated"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post that hidden children have display:block when visible

Comment: Place here your code. OR you can create https://jsfiddle.net/ for this

Comment: Could you add a snippet please?